# Guardianproject FFMpeg Android library Clip path always go wrong

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, clip

I am trying to work with guardianproject with FFMpeg from here
https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

there is a Clip object which need to be passed the file path into it

My stored video file is "/storage/emulated/0/00Testing/clip.mp4"
so I create a new clip object as:

```
Clip clipVideo = new Clip("/storage/emulated/0/00Testing/clip.mp4");
```

but the clipVideo.duration always return "-1", it mean my path is wrong!
I am sure that file is exist !

please help me, I lost 2 days for this stuff!

thanks a lot !!

Comment: when you create object of Clip. default value for duration is set to -1

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
        Clip  clipIn= new Clip();
        FfmpegController ffmpegController = new FfmpegController(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
        clipIn.path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)+"/Video/cvplay.avi").getCanonicalPath();
```

and don't forget to use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```